# popover presentation disappear from Manual/Action segue menu in xcode 7.3.1

Tags: swift, storyboard, xcode7.3

I want to link between a UIButton to a custom PopoverViewController , but the popover presentation option disappear from the segue menu:

[image: the manual segue option Im getting when Ctrl+ link to the popoverViewController]

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on modal and then in the right menu, change kind with Popover

[image]